# AngularJS - Change properties of a class from a controller

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I won't harp on about the use-case for this (it's needed to override some behaviour in Angular Material which is causing bugs in Safari), but here's what I'm trying to do:

**HTML:**

```
<style>
  .changeme{
    height: 300px;
  }
</style>

<div class='changeme'>
  Some Text
</div>
```

My JS code looks at the height of the browser window, and I need to change the `height` attribute of `.changeme` dynamically from my controller.

I **CANNOT** do this via `ng-style`, as `Angular Material` strips ng-styles away from the particular element in question.

Is it possible to manipulate a `<style>` tag from Angular? Or are there any options for achieving this?

Comment: I dont think you can alter <style> tag. Need to have some work around.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi Damn. Any suggestions?

Comment: What about creating a directive which will insert another `<style>` with an `!important` for the `height` property?

Answer (score 2):

As already said, for **DOM** manipulation is best to use the **directive**.

Live example on [jsfddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/dxfdb8o1/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {

  })
  .directive('changeme', function() {
    return {
      restrict: "AC",
      scope: {
        elementHeight: "="
      },
      link: function(scope, elem) {
        scope.$watch('elementHeight', function() {
          elem.css('height', scope.elementHeight);
        });
      },
    }
  });
```

```css
.changeme {
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    Change height:
    <input ng-model="height" /> don't forget px. Example 100px.
    <div class='changeme' element-height="height">
      Some Text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can actually override Angular Material styles using `<style>` tag, but more recommended is using css file.

Secondly you can pass dynamic values for your css values by using jQuery. In jQuery you have function `css()`. You can pass to it the parameter name and it's value.

For example `.changeme.css('height', '300px');`

You can check more information about `css()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

You have to add that jQuery code in your controller. Those you can pass to it variables and manipulate it as you want.

Thirdly it is important to notice the order of your imported css files. For example if your Angular Material css file import is located most bottom in the range of css import files, then the most bottom file will override styles of classes or id's if they existed in above css files. Here's an example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="base.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="angularM.css">
```

Let's say `base.css` has style property called *width* for class called myClass and let's suppose angularM file has also style of that same class for that same property *width*. In this case the styles of angularM file will override the `base.css` file myClass styles.

I hope the explanation of last point was not complicated.